# Try Catch not working if exception is raised in return statement of try block

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, try-catch

Try Catch not working if exception is raised in return statement of try block. The below code still says :

> Could not find file 'c:\users\gaurav\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\MoviesMVS\MoviesMVS\Downloads\FromEC.jpeg'

Try catch is working fine when exception is raised in other statements.

```
    public ActionResult Download()
    {
        try
        {
            return File(@"\Downloads\FromEC.jpeg", "jpeg");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View("Error");
        }
    }
```

Comment: The File Method just creates a fitting ActionResult class. It does not open the file, touches the file or checks for existance or something else. The framework inspecting the ActionResult of that method will later try to read the file and will stumble over the fact that is could not find it, but that happens after the call of your Download method inside the framework. So try..catch behaviour is correct but your expectation is wrong.

Comment: @Ralf - Why don't you write this up as the answer?

Comment: Because in my opinion an answer should consist of a solution. With my knowledge i can just describe his misinterpretation but im missing the expertise in asp.net mvc for a solution on how to do it.